# Multiply Comma Seperated number together into one

Tags: javascript

I m getting values from multiple radio button and storing it into variables as a comma seperated number.

```
var coef = "1, 2, 3, 4";
```

output I want is multiplication of of all numbers;

```
total = 24
```

I m  trying to implement it in javascript/jquery. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with `split` and `reduce` if you pass in a comma separated string:

```js
var coef = "1, 2, 3, 4";

var total = coef.split(',').reduce( (a, b) => a * b );

console.log(total);
```

If you pass in an array, you don't need to split:

```js
var coef = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var total = coef.reduce( (a, b) => a * b );

console.log(total);
```

Comment: I m getting split is not a function error.

<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/5DYWDHE" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/5DYWDHE"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

I m passing numbers via array and want to multiply it together intot total

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var coef = "1, 2, 3, 4";
var total = coef.trim().split(",").reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator * value, 1);
```

If array

```
var total = coef.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator * value, 1);
```

**Demo**

```js
var coef = "1, 2, 3, 4";
var total = coef.trim().split(",").reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator * value, 1);
console.log(total)
```

Comment: The initial value parameter of the reduce function isn't necessary.

Comment: @carsten I m getting trim is not a function error. I m passing array\

Comment: Then it's because it's an array and you have shown a string.  updated example